# iOS - UIViewControllers sharing a screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I'm writing an app that has two sections like this:

[image]

The idea is that on the top half I'm creating a request, and on the bottom I'm displaying the results. As my `UIViewController` subclass grows and grows I thought it might be a good idea to split that into two `UIViewController`s. (So what I'm trying to do is something like a `UISplitViewController`).

Although I know it's possible programmatically I'd like to put both `UIViewController`s in the screen from the Interface Builder so I can manage autolayouts and design there. Dragging and dropping doesn't work there.

Is that possible? And more important - is that a good design or should I stick to the rule "One view controller for one screen"?

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: iOS 6 only. Thanks for asking - that's important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom container view controller to achieve what you want. See:

- WWDC 2011 #102 on [UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) (Apple developer ID required)
- the [containment section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12) of the *View Controller Programming Guide*
- the [containment section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) of the *UIViewController Reference* document

In short, since iOS 5, you no longer have to have a single view controller. Just make sure you call the necessary containment related calls. And iOS 6 makes it easier to design the storyboards for custom containers with the "container view" object.

Answer (score 1):

Apple have stated (WWDC 2012, Evolution of View Controllers, I think) that the "screenful" is no longer appropriate. A view controller should manage a self-contained chunk of functionality.

As of iOS5 you can compose an interface of multiple view controllers using view controller containment (`addChildViewController:` and so forth). As of iOS6 you can do this in interface builder using containers and containment segues.

You will of course need a view controller to hold your two child view controllers - this *will* hold a screenful of content, and will usually perform any coordination between the two children.